# Prevent an event from running for a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview with the following code:

```
    private void datagridview_CustomerList_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_continueCellEdit)
        {
            _continueCellEdit = true;
            return;
        }

        if (datagridview_CustomerList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].OwningColumn.Name == ColumnNames.NewRateColumn.ToString())
        {
            var row = datagridview_CustomerList.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            var font = datagridview_CustomerList.Font;

            if (modMain.SSS_ToDecimal(row.Cells[ColumnNames.NewRateColumn.ToString()].Value) > 0)
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(font, FontStyle.Regular);
                if (modMain.SSS_ToDecimal(row.Cells[ColumnNames.BudgetBalanceColumn.ToString()].Value) > 0)
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = color_BudgetCustomers;
                else
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = color_OriginalColor;
            }
            else
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = color_ZeroCharge;
                row.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(font, FontStyle.Strikeout);
            }
        }

    }

    private void datagridview_CustomerList_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        _continueCellEdit = false;
        PaintRow(datagridview_CustomerList.Rows[e.RowIndex]);
    }
```

I am using the _continueCellEdit to prevent the CellEndEdit event from running. I can use this to disable/enable the event:

```
datagridview_CustomerList.CellEndEdit += datagridview_CustomerList_CellEndEdit;
```

This doesn't help cause I don't have a place to put the above line. If I put it in the datagridview_CustomerList_CellMouseDoubleClick it still runs after this event has finished.

I am prob overthinking this since I didn't get to take lunch, I gotta blame something but...

Is there a better way of handling this instead of using a bool?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use the [chain of responsibility](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rizvianzish/structuralpattern08292007115722AM/structuralpattern.aspx) pattern, but I honestly don't think your use case warrants it and the bool solution is fine.

That said it could be implemented something like this

The first handler in the chain would  basically look like

```
 public DoubliClickHanlder : IChain
 {
    public IChain NextHandler(get;set;)

 public void ProcessEvent(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
      if !(this.continueCellEdit && this.NextHandler!= null)
          NextHandler.ProcessEvent(sender,e) 
    }

 }
```

and the second handler would look like

```
public GridColorSetter : IChain
{
 public IChain NextHandler(get;set;)
public void ProcessEvent(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
       if (datagridview_CustomerList.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].OwningColumn.Name == ColumnNames.NewRateColumn.ToString())
        {
            var row = datagridview_CustomerList.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            var font = datagridview_CustomerList.Font;

            if (modMain.SSS_ToDecimal(row.Cells[ColumnNames.NewRateColumn.ToString()].Value) > 0)
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(font, FontStyle.Regular);
                if (modMain.SSS_ToDecimal(row.Cells[ColumnNames.BudgetBalanceColumn.ToString()].Value) > 0)
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = color_BudgetCustomers;
                else
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = color_OriginalColor;
            }
            else
            {
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = color_ZeroCharge;
                row.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(font, FontStyle.Strikeout);
            }
        }

    if (this.NextHandler!= null)
      this.NextHandler.ProcessEvent;

 }
}
}
```

Then it you could write the following

```
DoubleClickHandler dch = new DoubleClickHandler () {NextHandler= new GridColorSetter()}
this.datagridview_CustomerList.CellEndEdit += dch.ProcessEvent;
```

Comment: lol yeah I think I'll stick with the boolean. Thanks for the alternate idea. That does give me some ideas on a few other issues.